# Blank Cell if in Excel

Tags: excel

I've created a speadsheet to total figures all depending on date, I've successfully done that with the formula below

```
=IF(D6< NOW(),"Paid","Not Paid" )
```

My problem is... I have for the rest of the spread sheet where I haven't inputted a date in `D6` my paid, not paid column displays "Paid"

Image: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=IF(LEN(D6)=0,"", IF(D6 <= NOW(), "Paid", "Not Paid"))
```

Comment: Sorry... I got a function name crossed.  I just updated to have `LENGTH` replaced with `LEN`, so you are good now.

Comment: That displays, not paid.. Was hoping for it to be blank.. Thanks!

Comment: Works Great! Only problem is that for todays date it is marked 'not paid', but marks 'paid' for tomorrows date?

Comment: Adjusted.  When posting your question, please include all issues you are having with your code so that the question can be answered most efficiently.  Thanks and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the unwanted `"Paid"` for blank cells in D column, here is what you need to put in G column

```
=IF(D27="","",IF(D27<=NOW(),"Paid","Not Paid"))
```

[image: Excel Formula]

Comment: Looks like you made the screen shot before the reqs were changed to have `<=` :)

Comment: You caught me :) red handed @JeremyMiller